# RadioButton - Checked if radiobutton is checked inside a radiogroup - Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm having problem checking if one of the `radiobutton` is selected inside inside my `radiogroup`, I've tried a lot of methods like  `if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)` but still not working on my code.

On my logcat `String selectedansText = selectedans.getText().toString();`
in this line my logcat is pointing the problem, can someone help me?

I also tried `.isChecked` but it is not working.

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         RadioButton selectedans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
         String selectedansText = selectedans.getText().toString();

         if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()== -1){
             Toast.makeText(grade_four_post_test.this, 
                           "choose answer", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } else { //do something }
```

PS: `bt` is declared properly

```
01-28 22:27:07.390 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
01-28 22:27:07.391 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
01-28 22:27:07.391 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-28 22:27:07.391 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-28 22:27:07.392 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-28 22:27:07.392 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
01-28 22:27:07.392 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 22:27:07.393 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-28 22:27:07.393 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
01-28 22:27:07.393 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
01-28 22:27:07.394 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 22:27:07.394 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
01-28 22:27:07.396 27612-27612/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal:second, PID: 27612
                                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                at com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal.grade_level.post_test.grade_four_post_test$1.onClick(grade_four_post_test.java:117)
                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 22:27:07.400 696-9034/system_process V/Provider/Settings:  from settings cache , name = dropbox:data_app_crash , value = null
01-28 22:27:07.401 696-9034/system_process D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=128KB
01-28 22:27:07.401 696-9034/system_process D/dalvikvm: create new thread
01-28 22:27:07.401 696-9034/system_process D/dalvikvm: new thread created
01-28 22:27:07.401 696-9034/system_process D/dalvikvm: update thread list
01-28 22:27:07.402 696-28496/system_process D/dalvikvm: threadid=79: interp stack at 0x63b53000
01-28 22:27:07.402 696-28496/system_process D/dalvikvm: threadid=79: created from interp
01-28 22:27:07.402 696-9034/system_process D/dalvikvm: start new thread
01-28 22:27:07.402 696-9034/system_process V/Provider/Settings:  from settings cache , name = send_action_app_error , value = 1
01-28 22:27:07.402 696-28496/system_process D/dalvikvm: threadid=79: notify debugger
01-28 22:27:07.403 696-9034/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal/.grade_level.post_test.grade_four_post_test
```

Comment: where is the logcat pointing to? You should post the logcat output....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get NullPointerException for this:

```
  RadioButton selectedans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
         String selectedansText = selectedans.getText().toString();//NullPointer
```

because if no `RadioButton` is selected, `findViewById` will not work, so Your `RadioButton` is not initialized. You should do it like this:

```
 int radioButtonId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

if(radioButtonId!=-1){

   //do Your stuff
    RadioButton selectedans = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioButtonId);
    String selectedansText = selectedans.getText().toString();

}else{
 Toast.makeText(grade_four_post_test.this, 
                           "choose answer", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: it work!, thank you :D. i marked this correct coz of full details,

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      //Start your work here

    }

});
```

Comment: this makes no difference to the questions code and does not answer the question...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()== -1) this means no radio button is selected.
```

in else part Add below lines

```
int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton selectedans = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
Toast.makeText(grade_four_post_test.this,selectedans.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: and remove  RadioButton selectedans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                                      String selectedansText = selectedans.getText().toString();
 line

Comment: i can't remove that line because i'm getting the text value of the radiobutton selected on my radiogroup and comparing into another string variable.

Comment: in else you can add that lines